# Accessing internet data Swift

Tags: html, ios, swift

I was wondering how you could access data from a website using swift. The idea is that I'd be able to update the website with information rather dan having to update the entire Application. I think i would only need to read in text from a server (which I'm willing to buy if necessary (which i think it is?)).

Just to be clear, I don't need the website to show in the view, I only need the text to be imported in to my code ;-)

(I'm using Swift (Xcode), and I'm fairly familiar to HTML)

Comment: you can use `NSURLConnection` or a framework like _Alamo Fire_ (https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of resources and documentation. Look at `NSURLConnection` and `NSURLRequest`. That lets you create asynchronous downloads of data via an HTTP Get request. There's also `NSURLSession`, which lets you manage multiple downloads, even when your app isn't running. There are also third party libraries like `AFNetworking` (An Objective-C framework that you can use from Swift) or `AlamoFire`, which is a native Swift framework.

I recommend starting with `AlamoFire`. It's elegant and fairly simple to use.

You need to learn about async processing and completion handlers before you're going to be able to do any of this however. Study up on async networking and completion handlers before you begin or you will make the same mistakes that thousands of novice iOS developers make.